# codeigniter fetching date by comparing date in sql table not working

Tags: php, mysql, date, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have simple form in CodeIgniter with a date field and a submit button. I also have an SQL table where there are few values and date column values looks like: 21-11-2022 16:19:14, 21-11-2022. 15:51:41.

As the date saved in table is like date and time and my input type date gives only date, I did the following code in my model to get all the values within a date like below:

```
$this->db->select('userid, roll, amount, txnnumber, bankref, txntype, txndate, authstatus, feetype');
$date1=$sid." 00:00:00";
$date2=$sid." 11:59:59";
$this->db->where('txndate <=',$date1);
$this->db->where('txndate >=',$date2);
```

However this doesn't give me any data. Can anyone please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The poster left out a few critical bits of information regarding his form values and how things are stored in his database. His form date format is `mm/dd/yyyy` and his database format is `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss` in a varchar column.

To correctly compare the dates both the input form value and the database value needed to be converted to UNIX timestamps so they could be compared.

```
$this->db->select('userid, roll, amount, txnnumber, bankref, txntype, txndate, authstatus, feetype 
WHERE 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(SUBSTR(txndate,7,4),SUBSTR(txndate,4,2),SUBSTR(txndate,1,2))) <= $entered_date 
OR 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(SUBSTR(txndate,-4),SUBSTR(txndate,4,2),SUBSTR(txndate,1,2))) => $entered_date');
```

Comment: i tried this, but still i get empty data, i even tried it like this $this->db->where("DATE(txndate)", $sid);

Comment: If you are trying to look for things within a certain date range then you need a single `WHERE` to check the date range in one shot. I modified my answer to reflect that.

Comment: i tried this, but it gives me site cant be reached error

Comment: That sounds completely unrelated.

Comment: the error came when i added this where statment

Comment: Adding that would not have caused your site to not be able to be reached.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249785/discussion-between-dave-and-zno).